# enable_shared_from_this (c++0x): what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm just toying around with the smart pointers in the upcoming new c++ standard. However I fail to grasp the usage of the shared_from_this function. Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class CVerboseBornAndDie2 : public std::enable_shared_from_this<CVerboseBornAndDie2>
{
public:
    std::string m_Name;
    CVerboseBornAndDie2(std::string name) : m_Name(name)
    {
        std::cout << m_Name << " (" <<  this << ") is born!" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~CVerboseBornAndDie2()
    {
        std::cout << m_Name << " (" <<  this << ") is dying!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    CVerboseBornAndDie2* vbad = new CVerboseBornAndDie2("foo");
    std::shared_ptr<CVerboseBornAndDie2> p = vbad->shared_from_this();
}
```

and it throws a std::bad_weak_ptr exception in the line

```
std::shared_ptr<CVerboseBornAndDie2> p = vbad->shared_from_this();
```

if I instead do

```
std::shared_ptr<CVerboseBornAndDie2> p(vbad);
```

it works and I can afterwards do

```
std::shared_ptr<CVerboseBornAndDie2> p2 = p.get()->shared_from_this();
```

so must the object belong to one shared_ptr before I can use shared_from_this? But how can I know this beforehand?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is a precondition of using `shared_from_this` that there must exist at least one `shared_ptr` which owns the object in question. This means that you can only use `shared_from_this` to retrieve a `shared_ptr` that owns an object to which you have a reference or pointer, you cannot use it to find out if such an object is owned by a `shared_ptr`.

You need to rework your design so that either you are guaranteed that any such object is being managed by a `shared_ptr` or that you don't ever need to know or finally (and least desirably) you create some other way of managing this knowledge.

Comment: Couldn't you just put a try-block around a call to shared_from_this if you wanted to find out if the object is held by a shared_ptr?  I don't know how it is specified in the (upcoming) standard, but it doesn't appear to be undefined behavior -- it is throwing an exception.

Comment: @nobar: This would be inferently unsafe. You would be relying on undocumented implementation detail. `shared_from_this` is not a method for testing whether an object is owned by a shared pointer; it is a method for retrieving a shared pointer from an object that you _know_ is owned by a shared pointer.

Comment: I think you are right.  The C++0x draft says "There shall be at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns &t.", but it doesn't say what happens otherwise.  It shows an implementation in terms of weak_ptr (which would imply that an exception will be thrown on error), but that is only a "suggestion".  I wonder if the error-handling will eventually be better specified.

Answer (score 16):

To extend Charles answer, when you use `enable_shared_from_this` you usually want something like below in order to guarantee that there exists a shared_ptr.

```
class my_class : public std::enable_shared_from_this<my_class>
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<my_class> create() // can only be created as shared_ptr
    {
         return std::shared_ptr<my_class>(new my_class());
    }
private
    my_class(){} // don't allow non shared_ptr instances.
};
```

Comment: `create()` should be `static`, doesn't it?

Comment: And to have sharing by default, you could use something along the lines of: `try { return shared_from_this(); } catch (const bad_weak_ptr&) { return make_shared<C>(); }`