# enable_shared_from_this - empty internal weak pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm using `enable_shared_from_this<Base>` and then inherit from `Base`. When trying to use `shared_from_this()` in `Derived`'s constructor (not initializer list), I get an exception. Turns out that the internal weak pointer is null and doesn't point to `this` at all. How can this happen? My other use case of exactly this works perfectly fine. I don't even know where to start. I looked down at the source code of `enable_shared_from_this`, and it looks to me like that pointer would always be nullptr.

Comment: Not really a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428023/enable-shared-from-this-c0x-what-am-i-doing-wrong

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot call `shared_from_this()` in the object's constructor.  `shared_from_this()` requires that the object is owned by at least one `shared_ptr`.  An object cannot be owned by a `shared_ptr` before it is constructed.

I would guess that the internal weak pointer is set when a `shared_ptr` takes ownership of the object for the first time.  Before that point, there is no reference count struct that the weak pointer can reference.

Answer (score 5):

[James McNellis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494786/enable-shared-from-this-empty-internal-weak-pointer/4494814#4494814) is right.

As for the explanation of the `enable_shared_from_this` template itself, which as you observe appears to do nothing, note 7 at the bottom of [this page](http://www.drdobbs.com/184402026) explains:

> ...the template
>   `enable_shared_from_this` holds a
>   `weak_ptr` object that points to the
>   derived object. There's a
>   chicken-and-egg problem, though, about
>   how to initialize that `weak_ptr` object
>   when there is no corresponding
>   `shared_ptr` object. The implementation
>   trick is that the constructors for
>   `shared_ptr` know about
>   `enable_shared_from_this`, and set the
>   `weak_ptr` object during construction of
>   a `shared_ptr` object that owns a
>   resource that has
>   `enable_shared_from_this` as a public
>   base class.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, `shared_from_this()` picks a `shared_ptr` pointing to `this` and returns a copy of it.

In the constructor, there is no `shared_ptr` pointing to `this`.