# tr1::bad_weak_ptr

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [enable_shared_from_this - empty internal weak pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494786/enable-shared-from-this-empty-internal-weak-pointer)

```
AuthConnection::AuthConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    :Connection(io_service)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<AuthHandler>h (new AuthHandler( shared_from_this() ));
    this->handler=h;
}
```

shared_from_this() should return a ptr of Connection , but it's throwing this exception

```
tr1::bad_weak_ptr
```

i dont have a clue what's wrong here!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing your usage of `shared_from_this()` is wrong.

It should be used in a class as follows:

```
class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
public:

    shared_ptr<Y> f()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
}
```

Then you can call `y->f()` to get the this pointer of the class.

It's more then merely this, the actual issue is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494786/enable-shared-from-this-empty-internal-weak-pointer) question and answer.  It has to do with the fact that you can't call `shared_from_this()` in the ctor of the derived object.

Comment: i tested it and the same error,notice that am driving from it so i dont really need a method to get the ptr

Comment: @Mixed I added something to my answer.

Comment: so i made `boost::shared_ptr<Connection> con=this->getThis(); boost::shared_ptr<AuthHandler>h (new AuthHandler(con));` and still the same error , or did i get it wrong!?

Comment: @MixedCoder We don't know what the relationships between `Connection`, `AuthConnection` and `AuthHandler` are; we don't know what *it* is in "*notice that am driving from it*" (sic) nor do we even know **where** we're supposed to notice it. By this point you should expect an answer from the Psychic Squad.