# std::enable_shared_from_this ... Does a new shared_ptr know to take shared_from_this()?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a class that derives from `enable_shared_from_this` ... (Recently been added to std from Boost)

```
class Blah : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Blah>
{

};
```

I know I should create shared pointers from an instance like this:

```
Blah* b = new Blah();
std::shared_ptr<Blah> good(b->shared_from_this());
```

Question is, will it take the object's weak_ptr implicitly if I do something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Blah> bad(new Blah());
```

Or will it just create a seperate shared pointer counter ? (which i suspect)

Comment: Are `B` and `Blah` supposed to be the same thing? I've assumed so.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428023/enable-shared-from-this-c0x-what-am-i-doing-wrong/4428083#4428083

Comment: Yes sorry, fixed that .... B = Blah

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Blah* b = new Blah();
std::shared_ptr<Blah> good(b->shared_from_this()); // bad, *b is not yet owned
```

This is incorrect. For `shared_from_this` to work, `b` must already be owned by at least one `shared_ptr`. You must use:

```
std::shared_ptr<Blah> b = new B();
Blah* raw = b.get();
std::shared_ptr<Blah> good(raw->shared_from_this()); // OK because *raw is owned
```

Of course, in this trivial example it is easier to use:

```
std::shared_ptr<Blah> good(b);
```

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with:

```
std::shared_ptr<Blah> bad(new Blah());
```

Because `new B()` creates a new `B` there can be no other separate shared pointer count in existence for the newly created `B` object.

Comment: So, if you have a shared pointer to it, why would you want to use shared_from_this(), just pass around the shared_pointer? I'm missing the point...

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: Yes, that's usually a better approach. `shared_from_this()` just allows you to cope with situations where you have to pass a raw pointer through an interface and wish to retrieve a shared pointer that co-owns it, providing that you _know_ that the object is already owned by a shared pointer.

Comment: enable_shared_from_this creates a local member weak_ptr that watches "this" .... So, if it already watches "this" (from construction) why wouldn't you be able to create a shared_ptr from it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, are you asking about a specific implementation of `std::enable_shared_from_this` ?

Comment: Never-mind thanks... boost documentation: "There must exist at least one shared_ptr instance p that owns t."